# convert column value to comma seperated row values in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to convert column values from a table as comma separated row values in bigquery. I am able to perform this in sql server using below code,

```
SELECT @PivotColumnNames= ISNULL(@PivotColumnNames + ',','')
+ QUOTENAME(close_month)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT close_month FROM #temp) AS close_months
```

but not sure how to do it in bigquery.

[image: input]

[image: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you try below ?

```sql
SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT close_month) AS close_months FROM `your_table`;
```

If you want a each month wrapped with brackets, you can concatenate them.

```sql
SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT '[' || close_month || ']') AS close_months FROM `your_table`;
```